# preg_replace_callback() working mechanism

Tags: php, regex

I have a string "http://somethingafter.com/(something)?after=paren" which is being passed through a function preg_replace_callback();
i.e

```
$text = "http://somethingafter.com/(something)?after=paren";
$ret = ' ' . $text;

  $ret = preg_replace_callback('#([\s>])([\w]+?://[\w\\x80-\\xff\#$%&~/.\-;:=,?@\[\]+]*)#is', 'url_clickable_cb', $ret);

function url_clickable_cb($matches) {
  $ret = '';
  $url = $matches[2];

  if ( empty($url) ){
    return $matches[0];
  }

  $href = str_replace('&nbsp;',"",$url);

  // removed trailing [.,;:] from URL
  if ( in_array(substr($url, -1), array('.', ',', ';', ':')) === true ) {
    $url = substr($url, 0, strlen($url)-1);
  }
  return $matches[1] . "<a class=\"custom-tag\" href=\"$href\" rel=\"nofollow\" target=\"_blank\">$url</a>";
}
```

but this function is returning

```
<a class="custom-tag" href="http://somethingafter.com/" rel="nofollow" target="_blank">http://somethingafter.com/</a>(something)?after=parens
```

What I want is I want all that above text to be inside the `<a>` tag.
Any help would be appreciated.
PS: "https://test/en/technology/7/details#sort_type=ds_created&sort_order=desc"
I want this string to be converted as a URL like Stackoverflow is doing.

**Current Output:**
[image]

**Expected Output:**
[image]

Comment: > What I want is I want all that above text to be inside

Can you explain exactly what you want as the output? Is it the entire url?

Comment: @Timo I have attached the expected output

Comment: Your regular expression is preventing this from working; It is stopping on the `(`: https://regex101.com/r/vPVjet/1 

That means that the capture stops and the `</a>` is placed in the middle of the first link: https://3v4l.org/hWfQ0

Comment: Thanks I did manage to fix for that URL but now I also need for the text that's wrapped with ``` " ``` . This regex will surely fail for it. https://regex101.com/r/T6a6Yz/1

Comment: That is prevented by this part of your regular expression: `([\s>])`. That states that the url needs to start with either a whitespace or a `>`. The check for a word boundary `\w` already states that the match should not be preceded with another textual character. I think removing `([\s>])` might fix your issue.

Comment: @Timo sorry for late response. I can't remove that. My text can have multiple URL in it and I need to append space for the first one, so it works for other URL present on that text. .i.e  `https://test.com this is a test text go to www.google.com to find out more. `

Answer (score 0):

```
$ret = ' ' . $text;

  $ret = preg_replace_callback('#([\s>])([\w]+?://[\w\\x80-\\xff\#$%&~/.\-;:=,?@\[\]+]*)#is', 'url_clickable_cb', $ret) ."</a>";

function url_clickable_cb($matches) {
  $ret = '';
  $url = $matches[2];

  if ( empty($url) ){
    return $matches[0];
  }

  $href = str_replace('&nbsp;',"",$url);

  // removed trailing [.,;:] from URL
  if ( in_array(substr($url, -1), array('.', ',', ';', ':')) === true ) {
    $url = substr($url, 0, strlen($url)-1);
  }
  return $matches[1] . "<a class=\"custom-tag\" href=\"$href\" rel=\"nofollow\" target=\"_blank\">$url";
}
```

Comment: Code without any explanation are rarely helpful. Stack Overflow is about learning, not providing snippets to blindly copy and paste.
 Please edit your question and explain how it answers the specific question being asked. See [How to Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).